# Circuit with WS2818B and MOSFET SI2303 is not working

Tags: ws2811

I want to make an LED driver like the https://oshwlab.com/arduino12/ws2811_driver but with WS2818B instead of WS2811 because of the backup data line. Unfortunately nothing happens when I put Data to DIN. I only get 12V or 0V on U1/OUTR  (random).
This is my schematic:

[image]

The datasheet says: 
 
[image]

I already replaced R1 with 2.7k, but nothing changed. I get 5.1V on VDD/U1 and 12V/0V on OUTR/U1 randomly. When I manually short Q1/gate to GND, the LED turns on as expected.

As mentioned in this FastLED-Thread (https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/issues/1385), I tried several pixel-configs, including WS1812, WS2812, WS2811, but none of them worked for me. This is my code:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <FastLED.h>

#define NUM_LEDS 1  //number of LEDs

#define DATA_PIN 27
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];    //led array

void setup() {

     FastLED.addLeds<WS2813, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);

}

void loop() {
  // Turn the LED on, then pause
  leds[0] = CRGB::White;
  FastLED.show();
  delay(500);
  // Now turn the LED off, then pause
  leds[0] = CRGB::Black;
  FastLED.show();
  delay(500);
}
```

The FastLED version is 3.5 (newest so far). 
 What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have scope plots of your signals? Make sure that the timings are within specs of the datasheet.

Comment: Also, there are different variants: WS2812, WS2812B, WS2812C (maybe more?). They aren't 100% compatible.

Comment: Can you link to the datasheet from which you pulled that circuit diagram? The datasheets I'm finding for this part have the same diagram, but with 5V on the supply rail, which makes me think I'm not finding the right datasheet for your part.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. This is the datasheet: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1134590/WORLDSEMI/WS2818B.html

Comment: unfortunately I don't have a scope... I wondered why everyone in every thread gets the ws2818 running, weather it's fastled or the Adafruit neopixel library.

Comment: Looking at your code, it's essentially the same as the [Blink example](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/blob/master/examples/Blink/Blink.ino), so not much room for errors here. Have you checked your pin configuration, for example did you measure any 'activity' on the data line using a voltmeter?

Comment: Yes, I already checked the pin configuration. Other types, for example a strip of WS2812 just works fine...

Comment: I'm at a total loss here. So a strip of WS2812 works fine, while a single WS2812B causes issues?

Comment: You said you don't have a scope, but could you connect the DIN of the known-working strip of WS2812 to the DO pin of this circuit and try to run that? If the strip still works, that lets you know that the digital circuitry in your WS2818 is mostly working.

Comment: Oh, and have you checked the polarity of U1? Soldering chips flipped 180 degrees has definitely bitten me in the butt before, and might explain the weird/"random" impedance you were seeing when probing OUTR.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems I can see:

For U1, only the WS2818B claims to have a "built in VR-tube"/"internal LDO." I suspect both of these terms may be mistranslations, but the gist is that only the -B has internal voltage regulation allowing you to use 12V supply with a bias resistor. You haven't fully specified the part number, and if you have the -A, the absolute maximum rating on VDD is 5.3V and the part may simply be shorting out. It's likely damaged. (If you do have the -B, they recommend a 2.7K bias resistor, not 3.3K. Part should be fine but you should change the resistor.)

As for those transistors, their absolute max Vds may be 20V, but their absolute max Vgs is 8V. MOSFETs have negligible gate current, so those gate resistors aren't lowering the voltage, and you're operating them out of spec by applying 12V Vgs. I see that the OSHWlab link is also doing that, and maybe it worked for them, but it's out of spec.

Comment: Pardon, I have WS2818B, which should work with 12V. As I mentioned before, I already changed the resistor to 2.7k.
3. where do you see the max. vgs 8V? In the following datasheet Vgs is +-20V. (https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2005181303_UMW-Youtai-Semiconductor-Co---Ltd--SI2303_C545575.pdf)

Comment: @kokospalme ah, I didn't notice that part number is used by a few different manufacturers. I was looking at Vishay's SI2302, I assume you've got the datasheet for your manufacturer's version.